# Import Error: No Module named 'Tkinter'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple gui and run in IDLE but every time I run it , it gives me the error :`Import Error: No module named 'Tkinter'`

This is my code if anybody is wondering:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

I have also tried to verify if i have installed tkinter or not with command `import tkinter` and `tkinter._test()` and it shows that I have tkinter installed.

Comment: Compare what you've said with your actual code... `import tkinter` is not what you're running, or what module the error says is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lowercase T for `tkinter` import statement for Python 3 :

```
import tkinter
```

IF your using python2 it's:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

But your using python3, so it's:

```
from tkinter import *
```

Comment: using all lowercase works but i had seen a code on the internet having the 'T' capital and it worked. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That is Python 2 version of the module. You are using Python 3 and on python 3 the module name is tkinter.